# Prove that if $A^{n+1} =0$, then $A^n=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, independence

Let $A$ be a square matrix of order $n$. Suppose $A^m=0$ and $A^{m-1}$ is  not zero for some integer $m \ge 2$

Show that $\{u,Au,\ldots, $ $A^{m-1}u\}$ is linearly independent, where $u$ is the vector in $R^n$ such that $A^{m-1}u \neq 0$

Prove that if $A^{n+1} =0$, then $A^n=0$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: If $A^{m-1}u=0$ then $\{u,Au,...,A^{m-1}u\}$ is clearly not linearly independent

Comment: Hint: Cayley Hamilton theorem might be useful.

Comment: @JoaquinLiniado $A^m = 0$, but $A^{m-1}$ is non-zero.

Comment: Induction for the first part, maybe.

Comment: I have not learnt Cayley Hamilton's Theorem but will look that up, thanks\

Comment: @Mark But $A^{m-1}u =0$, so no set containing it can be linearly independent.

Comment: @Mark if $A^{m-1}u=0$ then $\{u,Au,...,A^{m-1}u\}=\{u,Au,...,0\}$ which is linearly dependant..

Comment: Cayley-Hamilton is an excellent theorem to know, but I would hesitate to use it here, for two reasons: you can prove it with a more intuitive, elementary method, and one way to prove Cayley-Hamilton is using some of the facts you're trying to prove.

Comment: @JoaquinLiniado I'm seeing that $A^{m-1}$ is not zero in the problem.  The $A^{n+1} = 0\implies A^n = 0$ I was interpreting in terms of the size (or order here?) of the matrix.  If it's true for general $n$ this problem is much different.

Comment: Apologies. The u should make $A^m-1$ not zero

Answer (score 4):

Take an arbitrary linear combination, totaling $0$:

$$c_1 u + c_2 Au +  c_3 A^2u + \ldots + c_m A^{m-1}u = 0.$$

What happens if you take $A^{m-1}$ of both sides? What can you conclude about $c_1$? Now what about when you take $A^{m-2}$ of both sides?

Let's say you manage to conclude that the list of $m$ vectors is linearly independent. They have to lie in a finite-dimensional space with dimension $n$. Is it really possible for $m > n$?

EDIT:

Suppose $A^{n+1} = 0$, but for the sake of contradiction, $A^n \neq 0$. By definition of the zero transformation, there exists a vector $u$ that $A^n$ fails to send to $0$. By the same token, $A^{n+1}$ sends $u$ to $0$, like every other vector!

So, we have the same situation as the first problem. We have a vector $u$ and transformation $A$ such that $A^{m-1} u \neq 0 = A^m u$. In this case, we have $m = n + 1$. So, this implies we have a linearly independent set:
$$\lbrace u, Au, A^2u, A^3u, \ldots, A^n u \rbrace$$
BUT, this set has $n + 1$ elements, which is impossible in an $n$-dimensional space. Any linearly independent set can be extended into a basis (which would have to contain at least $n + 1$ vectors, and all bases must be of the same length $n$. This is a contradiction, so our assumption that $A^n \neq 0$ must have been wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I get the first part on establishing linear independence but I am confused over how the lack of independence of a set of n vectors from vector  u to $A^{n-1}u $ implies that $A^n = 0 $

Comment: If $A^n \neq 0$, then that means that there is some $u$ with $A^n u \neq 0$. But, $A^{n+1} = 0$, so $A^{n+1} u = 0$. Does that help?

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that this method is probably my favourite method for showing the independence of monomials $\lbrace 1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^n \rbrace$. If you take successive derivatives of a null linear combination of them, you quickly deduce that the coefficients must be $0$.

Comment: I am sorry but can't $A^nu$ lie in the null space of A making $A^{n+1} u = 0 $
 Thanks

Comment: @Anonymous I've updated my answer. Let me know if you're still confused about anything.

Comment: Got it thanks for your patience